# Classification of countable abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

For a finitely generated abelian group, there is a famous classification of these groups as form $\mathbb{Z}^r \oplus \mathbb{Z}/q_1\mathbb{Z} \oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{Z}/q_n\mathbb{Z}$ with $r,n$ finite. I would like to know whether there is a classification of countable abelian groups. Is it true that every countable abelian group is isomorphic to the form $\mathbb{Z}^r \bigoplus \oplus_{i\in I} \mathbb{Z}/q_i\mathbb{Z}$ where $r$ is either finite or $\infty$ and $I$ is a countable set?

Comment: No. Cf. $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Is $\mathbb{Q}$ isomorohic to $\mathbb{Z}^\infty$?

Comment: @user119197 No. $\mathbb{Z}^\infty$ is free abelian; $\mathbb{Q}$ is not (it satisfies many relations).

Comment: Antoine, an invariant for an abelian group $A$ is the $\mathbf{Q}$-rank (aka rank), that is the largest cardinal of a $\mathbf{Z}$-free family. Another invariant is "being $p$-divisible", i.e. $pA=A$.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda "it satisfies many relations" is senseless.

Comment: One may say that in $\mathbb Q$ any two elements have a GCD; in $\mathbb Z^\infty$, not so.

Comment: We don't know all countable abelian groups. There are many, many abelian groups that don't fall into any of the categories mentioned here.

Comment: @YCor I don't understand; do you also think it is senseless to say that a free group (or a free abelian group) does not satisfy any (non-trivial) relations? If so, then I disagree. It can be stated more precisely (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ does not admit an abelian group presentation containing no defining relations), but lack of precision is not lack of sense.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Relations are not satisfied by groups, but by generators. It is senseless to speak of relations satisfied by $\mathbb Q$ without specifying a set of generators (which is far from canonical here). If you think otherwise, then show at least one “relation satisfied by $\mathbb Q$”.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda given the level of the question, I think that this lack of precision is not useful. Of course I know the meaningful statement which is hidden behind the sloppy statement "this group satisfies no relation", but anybody who can make this deduction probably can figure out that $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{Z}^{(\omega)}$ are not isomorphic without any hint.

Comment: This question was discussed in detail [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3927834/classification-of-countably-infinite-abelian-groups?rq=1)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I disagree with the statement "Relations are not satisfied by groups, but by generators"; I think the statement "free groups satisfy no non-trivial relations" is a perfectly meaningful statement, for example, and saying that it is senseless seems to conflate precision with sense. But I think this discussion might have run its course here as to the relevance of the question; I agree with YCor that the phrasing of my comment is not helpful for actually helping OP with the question.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda I'm sorry, but any way I look at it, "free groups satisfy no non-trivial relations" sounds correct, albeit little imprecise, whereas "$\mathbb Q$ satisfies many relations" sounds wrong (or not even wrong). The key difference here is that a free group has a canonical choice of generators to which the statement implicitly applies, while $\mathbb Q$ has no such canonical generators, and it satisfies no nontrivial relations that are independent of the choice of generators.

Comment: Regarding this "many relations" issue, I would suggest plopping down some judiciously chosen quantifiers: In a free group there exists a canonical *set of generating sets* each of which satisfies no non-trivial relations; In $\mathbb Q$ any generating set satisfies many relations. Still rather foggy regarding the "m" word, but at least both sides are now plausible.